# Image hover with fade effect - keeping them centered

Tags: jquery, css, image

Is there any way to hover an image and replace it with another without using position absolute?

Right now my image is centered in a `span (display: block;)` with `text-align: center;` which is just fine.

I have tried multiple solutions with adding the image to the document and toggle them with jQuery:

```
$("span.image_hover").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("img:not(.secondary)").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    $(this).find("img.secondary").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("img:not(.secondary)").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    $(this).find("img.secondary").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  });
```

The problem with this solution is that it requires position absolute to the images and therefore destroying the center position - this is a problem as the website is responsive and on resize the images is on the left and not in the center of the screen (mobile device). The images is scaled and only used with their max-width (240px).

Is there anyway I can do this transition while keeping the image inline or centered somehow?

I can not figure out the URL's to the images. So appending _off/_on to images is not a possibility. They are generated on the server and sent to me as variables for use in the document.

Comment: ...just wondering...If the image is containned by a wraper in Normal flow which is the child of the absolute element?. Then you may keep it centered. Sorry if I miss the point...

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please. Better yet, how about a working jsFiddle example?

Comment: I dont know the size of the image when I resize the window. The image scale to fit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Aaarrrrh! It can be fixed by adding `max-width: 240px` to the `span.image_hover`.